# como diseñar un boton de pago variable mercado pago

Tags: c#, mercadopago

necesito hacer un boton de pago variable en mercado pago (estoy programando en c#) y el codigo con el que cuento y funcionaba era:

```html
MP mp = new MP("145738500374", "44evgkCoNyexvrviv4p1qm");

object[] objArray1 = new object[] { "{\"items\":[{\"title\":\"clases\",\"quantity\":1,\"currency_id\":\"ARS\",\"unit_price\":", Valor_Carga, "}],\"external_reference\":\"", (string)Session["nickUsuario"], "\"}" };
            
Hashtable hashtable = mp.createPreference(string.Concat(objArray1));

mp.getAccessToken();
            
Response.Redirect(((Hashtable)hashtable["response"])["init_point"].ToString());
```

si alguien me puede decir el script para que el codigo sea el de un boton variable, ahora marca error en la linea mp.getAccessToken()

Comment: que seria un boton variable?

Comment: por ejemplo mercado pago permite hacer un boton de 10 pesos pero no un boton que varie el pago segun el producto comprado